# Is it possible to use index.php instead of index.html in a vue.js project built with webpack?

Tags: php, vue.js, webpack

Well i've got some login in a different app built in just php and when i try to get those session vars i lose them. i was thinking i could solve that problem just changing the index.html instead index.php file just to get those vars.

this is my php file, it suppose that s_apps has an array of 
numbers, this works perfectly if i use just php.

Attention: the loggin is an app that we used(with my teammates), when we develope a new app we just call the session var in a new session.php file

```
foreach ( $_SESSION["s_apps"] as $a_p)
    {    
         if( $a_p == 19)
            {
                $access=1;
            }
    }
```

I tried adding this on config/index.js

```
proxyTable: {
      '/includes/peticiones.php': {
        target: 'http://localhost/dirse/',
        changeOrigin: true
    }
```

and is not working,

when I do the axios petition shows this message "Undefined index: s_apps in C:\xamppPHP\htdocs\Dirse\includes\sessions.php";

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-php-loader